# Magento 2 installation says var directory is not writable

Tags: magento2, nginx, php-7

I have a strange problem with my Magento 2 installation. The readiness check says my `var`-directory is not writable although it clearly is. I even set it to `777`. The other directories (`app/etc`, `pub/media`, `pub/static`) all have the same rights and they pass the test.

Anyone else encountered this problem upon installing? My configuration is Nginx / PHP7.0.4

Comment: how about your parent folder, before <-/var?

Comment: Also check if there are other files/folders within var. All have to be *writeable*

`chmod -R 777 var/`

Comment: IIRC this can happen if the directory already contains data when you try to install it.

Comment: also, the ownership permission on the install makes a big difference. Make sure that what every the ownership is, magento is able to write and create directories.

Comment: Please check the Ownership of that 'var' directory. May be Magento user don't have permission.

Answer (score 0):

It is referring to system /var directory also check /tmp .

Moreover if openbasedir config specified in `php.ini` does not include /var then browser user can not access that directory.

If it is so then add /var directory by appending :/var/ in config
after installation is complete revert to old permissions.